# How can I find the file name if it is hidden in the URL?

Tags: url, web, client-side

Say if I visit some website like: `http://www.example.com/SOMEFOLDER/`

As the file name is hidden from the URL, is there any method I can find it?

Comment: Nope, not reliably. Often there is no actual file name behind a URL, just a central router file that does things depending on what the URL is.

Answer (score 0):

You can not tell which file is being called from "outside" the webserver. You will need access to webserver to determine the file being called.

You can of course guess, index.html is a default that is used a lot. But you can easily alter this default in the webserver configuration.

It is also common to use specific route tactics. For example in *Apache* you can enable the the *mod_rewrite* module (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). This allows the admin to create specific routes based on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you use is the most common form of URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier. It is a string of characters used to identify a resource on the web.

There are a set of steps each web site (web application) takes to route a URI to an actual resource. These routing steps decide what gets served to the client. In some cases, a corresponding file may not even be present on the web server and the content could be generated dynamically by the web or application server. It all depends on how the web site is designed.

So, to answer your question - No, there is no generic way of identifying "the" file behind a URL.